# Counting how many time the values returned from a subquery are in a table? PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like so

```
name value
john success
bob  success
alex NULL
john success
.
.
.
```

I am running this query to get the all the names which have never been set as NULL.

```
SELECT name FROM table
WHERE value is NOT NULL
EXCEPT
SELECT name FROM table
WHERE value is null
```

This displays all the names which have never been NULL. Now I want to display in the result table a count  of how many times each of these names appeared in my table. So for John it should say count 2. I tried doing COUNT (*) FROM () using my above query as subquery, but it just counts occurrences of the name in the result table and not the original table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . .

```
select name, count(*)
from t
group by name
having count(*) filter (where value is null) = 0;
```